# How to connect MySQL with Java?

Tags: java, mysql

I have installed **MYSQLSERVER 5.1**.Then I installed mysql-connector-java-3.0.8-stable-bin.jar and put in drive c with folder core that is C:\core.Then in properties of computer I create user variable with variable name CLASSPATH and variable value:C:\core\mysql-connector-java-3.0.8-stable-bin.jar.

Now I have created database EMPLOYEE4 
My java code is:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

class MySQLTest{


    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        try {  
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
            Connection dbcon = DriverManager.getConnection(  
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/EMPLOYEE", "root", "root");  

        String query ="select count(*) from EMPLOYEE4 ";
             Connection dbCon = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

            //getting PreparedStatment to execute query
            stmt = dbCon.prepareStatement(query);

            //Resultset returned by query
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            while(rs.next()){
             int count = rs.getInt(1);
             System.out.println("count of stock : " + count);
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
            //Logger.getLogger(CollectionTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally{
           //close connection ,stmt and resultset here
        }

    }  
   }
```

I get error that java.sql.SQLEXCEPTION:communication link failure:java.IO.Exception underlying cause:Unexpected end of input stream

Comment: do you have a database called EMPLOYEE ?

Comment: Are you not using any IDE like NetBeans, Eclipse?

Comment: Yelling at us won't solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should be getting NPE. As you are executing your query on `dbCon` and not on `dbcon`

```
// initialize here
Connection dbcon = DriverManager.getConnection(  
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/EMPLOYEE", "root", "root");  

String query ="select count(*) from EMPLOYEE4 ";

// Null here
Connection dbCon = null;

// on dbCon which is null 
stmt = dbCon.prepareStatement(query);
```

**EDIT**

This how your code suppose to look like.

```
Connection dbcon = DriverManager.getConnection(  
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/EMPLOYEE", "root", "root"); 
String query = "select count(*) from EMPLOYEE4 ";
Statement stmt = dbcon.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

Comment: NO I REMOVED THAT STILL HAVE SAME EXCEPTION.

Comment: @shubhamJain : If you have a database with the name `EMPLOYEE4`, then your connection URL is wrong. It should be like `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/EMPLOYEE4`. You're referencing `EMPLOYEE4` as a table within the `EMPLOYEE` database in your SQL.

Comment: @LION:I CORRECTED IT BUT STILL SAME EXCEPTION.

Comment: Did you put these statements `Connection dbCon = null; Statement stmt = null; ResultSet rs = null;` statements at their proper places. Move them on top of the `try` block and close them in the `finally` block to prevent possible memory leak. More over, avoid unnecessary capitalization in your writing.

Comment: @LION:I have tried that too still same problem exist.Please Help

Comment: @shubhamJain You dont have `preparedStatement` instance or you have somewhere in your code?

Comment: I'm interested in the full exception stacktrace. Please edit your question to include the stacktrace.

Comment: @LION-Here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988347/how-to-connect-mysql-and-java

Comment: @shubhamJain I think you misunderstood Lion's request. You should edit the additional information into _this_ question, not create a new one. To accomplish this, look for the Edit link below your question.