# How to connect MYSQL and java

Tags: java, mysql

I have installed **MYSQLSERVER 5.1**.Then I installed mysql-connector-java-3.0.8-stable-bin.jar and put in drive c with folder core that is C:\core.Then in properties of computer I create user variable with variable name CLASSPATH and variable value:C:\core\mysql-connector-java-3.0.8-stable-bin.jar.

NOW i created database EMPLOYEE4 
MY JAVA code IS:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
class MySQLTest{


    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        try {  
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
            Connection dbCon = DriverManager.getConnection(  
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/EMPLOYEE4", "root", "root");  

        String query ="select count(*) from EMPLOYEE4 ";

        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

            //getting PreparedStatment to execute query
            stmt = dbCon.prepareStatement(query);

            //Resultset returned by query
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            while(rs.next()){
             int count = rs.getInt(1);
             System.out.println("count of stock : " + count);
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
            //Logger.getLogger(CollectionTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally{
           //close connection ,stmt and resultset here
        }

    }  
   }
```

I get error that

```
SQL Connection exceptionjava.sql.SQLException: Communication link failure: java.
io.IOException, underlying cause: Unexpected end of input stream

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **

java.io.IOException
MESSAGE: Unexpected end of input stream

STACKTRACE:

java.io.IOException: Unexpected end of input stream
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:339 )
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:78 2)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.j ava:1585)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:5 24)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:359)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager .java:512)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager .java:193)
at DbHelper.getConnection(DbHelper.java:34)
at DbHelper.main(DbHelper.java:466)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **
```

Comment: shubham do check the answers in previous posted question...dont post duplicates

Comment: did you check the database is running , i mean mysql service is on , sometimes it gives this problem , try running this query in database with command prompt

Comment: Yes my query is running.

Comment: I just [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987619/how-to-connect-mysql-with-java#comment24541881_16987771) you to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16987619/edit) your previous question to include the stacktrace you'r getting and **not** to post a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
java.io.IOException: Unexpected end of input stream
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:339 )
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:78 2)
```

indicates that you're picking up your JDBC driver via the classpath ok (see the fully qualified package names). You're not able to connect to your database, and I suspect your MySQL database isn't running, or isn't configured to accept connections on that port.

Can you connect to that port ? (via a simple telnet) or confirm that something is listening on that port using [netstat](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/netstat.mspx?mfr=true) ?

Comment: Hey I got the answer.I was using the 5.1.2 version of mysqlconnectorjava.I changed it to 5.0.8 and it worked fine.Thnx for all replies.